# Nested ternary operators

Tags: c#, refactoring, ternary-operator

I have this code:

```
_viewModel.PhoneDefault = user == null ? "" :
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PhoneDay) ?
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PhoneEvening) ?
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Mobile) ? "" : 
                user.Mobile) :
            user.PhoneEvening) :
         user.PhoneDay);
```

Is there a better way to write this to make it more readable?

Comment: Avoiding nested ternaries will certainly make the code more readable

Comment: Have you considered using "switch" ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your case you can write a helper function, like this:

```
// return the first parameter that isn't null or empty
public static string CoalesceStrings(params string[] src)
{
    foreach (var str in src)
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return str;
    return "";
}
```

Then just call it, like this:

```
_viewModel.PhoneDefault = user == null ? "" :
    CoalesceStrings(user.PhoneDay, user.PhoneEvening, user.Mobile);
```

Answer (score 7):

Write a seperate method to get the phone number, something like this:

```
public string GetDefaultPhone(User user)
        {
            if(user == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PhoneDay))
            {
                return user.PhoneDay;
            }

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PhoneEvening))
            {
                return user.PhoneEvening;
            }

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Mobile))
            {
                return user.Mobile;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
```

And then in your code:

```
_viewModel.PhoneDefault = GetDefaultPhone(user);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just answering because I haven't seen the approach I use in this kind of scenarios in any of the existing answers.

What about...

```
_viewModel.PhoneDefault = user == null ? string.Empty :
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PhoneDay)     ? user.PhoneDay :
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PhoneEvening) ? user.PhoneEvening :
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Mobile)       ? user.Mobile : 
    string.Empty;
```

It's inconvenient that you have to check by user nullness at the beginning because that forces to repeat `string.Empty`, but nevertheless I think it's pretty readable.

My two cents ;)

Comment: Another thing with nested ternaries apart from readability is maintainability - any slight change in the logic may make you break it down into plain conditionals - otherwise you'd have to keep enlarging the single statement. Nesting ternaries may look cool but in team work may not be worth the coolness - that's how I think about it. If the team is small and all have an accord over the usage, or just one person probably no difference :)

Answer (score 4):

Although I like Gabe's and Vladimir's answers the most. Here's a way to make nested ternaries look decipherable.

```
_viewModel.PhoneDefault =
  user == null
    ? ""
  : (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PhoneDay)
    ? (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PhoneEvening)
      ? (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Mobile)
           ? ""
         : user.Mobile)
      : user.PhoneEvening)
    : user.PhoneDay);
```

Granted, since you have to surround them with parentheses it makes it more difficult to do this. In JavaScript it actually comes out very elegant since it
allows for nested ternaries without the parentheses. Although your situation doesn't really need this syntax sometimes this syntax comes in very handy.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as long as the entries can be just null or valid:

```cs
    if (user == null)
    {
        _viewModel.PhoneDefault = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        _viewModel.PhoneDefault = user.PhoneDay ?? user.PhoneEvening ?? user.Mobile ?? string.Empty;
    }
```

You can even define an  extension method on string to convert empty strings to null and use it here, but I am just crazy.

If they can be an empty string, just use the other people answers. Jason's method is nice and clean.

Answer (score 1):

Now, with power of LINQ, you can make it simple and readable within single line like

```
_viewModel.PhoneDefault = user == null ? "" :
(new [] {user.PhoneDay, user.PhoneEvening, user.Mobile}).FirstOrDefault(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) ?? "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding some more parenthesis might make it more readable.  You could also break it down into a series of if/else statements

```
if (user != null)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PhoneDay))
    _viewModel.PhoneDefault = user.PhoneDay;
  else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PhoneEvening))
    _viewModel.PhoneDefault = user.PhoneEvening;
  else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Mobile))
    _viewModel.PhoneDefault = user.Mobile;
  else
    _viewModel.PhoneDefault = "";
}
```