# Triple conditional in variable assignation

Tags: c#

I have a simple variable assignation like:

```
  var color = order == "PO" ? Color.LightGreen : Color.LightBlue;
```

My question is, is it possible to add another condition to do a triple condition, somethoing like:

```
 var color = order == "PO" ? Color.LightGreen : "SO" ? Color.Lavender : Color.LightBlue;
```

So I want to say, if order equals to "PO" return LightGreen, if it's "SO" return Lavender and if it is different of those two return LightBlue. How can I achieve that? Regards

Comment: I would say at 3+ arguments, the reasoning for moving to a switch case start growing drastically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use an additional condition in the false section, as shown:

`var color = order == "PO" ? Color.LightGreen : order == "SO" ? Color.Lavender : Color.LightBlue;`

Readability is important, so what happens when you have a fourth case?  You may want to simply use `if/else` logic or a `switch` perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but it becomes hard to read, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103979/nested-ternary-operators) for examples of nested ternaries.

It's probably better to do a [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch):

```
  String order;
  Color color;
        switch (order)
        {
            case "PO":
                color = Color.LightGreen;
                break;
            case "SO":
                color = Color.Lavender;
                break;
            default:
                color = Color.LightBlue;
                break;
        }
```

edited to match the switch to your case ;)

Answer (score 0):

Three might be the very end of the ternary chaining looking good and you could switch to classic `if`s or a `switch-case` as mentioned, but also consider using a `Dictionary<string, Color>` for a quick lookup.